# PM2 start ecosystem.config.js not working in dockerfile in node js project

Tags: node.js, docker, pm2

I have a node js project where I am using Docker to update build to server.
I want to implement pm2 in cluster mode in server. So I added **ecosystem.config.js** file, which is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
apps: [{
name: "TestMyApp",
script: "app.js",
instances: "1",
exec_mode: "cluster",
autorestart: true
}]
}
```

Then in my **DockerFile**, I added commands like this

```
FROM node:16.9.1
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm install pm2 -g
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8005
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "ecosystem.config.js"] 
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

But when I update the build in server and run ***pm2 list***, my pm2 'TestMyApp' is not listed.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple `CMD` command. If there are multiple CMD command then only the last one will take effect. Therefore, your `pm2-runtime` is not actually executed.

Not sure why you need `npm start` if you already using `pm2-runtime`.

Comment: my server is not running when I remove npm start and only kept pm2-runtime.